# Alphabets to number converter but non english letter problem

Tags: php

I create small code alphabets to numbers code working perfect on English to numbers but when am trying to put Arabic Urdu alphabet to numbers function not working.

The below code is Working perfect on English alphabet:

```
$input = "JHON";
 
$remap = [
    "a" => '1',
    "A" => '1',
    "b" => '2',
    "B" => '2',
    "c" => '3',
    "C" => '3',
    "J" => '100',
    "H" => '10',
    "O" => '90',
    "N" => '200',
];
 
$array = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
    $c = $input[$i];
    $array[] = $remap[$c];
}
$star = "(" . implode(',', $array) . ")";
echo $star;
```

now problem is here when I put Arabic alphabet in array, then it's not working:

```
$input = "ب";
 
$remap = [
    "ا" => '200',
    "ب" => '300',
    "ج" => '50',
    "د" => '100',
];
 
$array = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($input); $i++) {
    $c = $input[$i];
    $array[] = $remap[$c];
}
$star = "(" . implode(',', $array) . ")";
echo $star;
```

The answer is 300  but output is grabage etc.

please tell me how can I manage it?

Comment: barmar brother when you use arabic alphabet in array automatic changed order its fine brother this order working on other function on non arabic its right to left so please give me solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String indexing with `[]` is not multibyte-safe. You need to use the `mb_XXX` functions when processing languages like Arabic.

```
<?php
$input = "ب";

$remap = [
    "ا" => '200',
    "ب" => '300',
    "ج" => '50',
    "د" => '100',
];

$array = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < mb_strlen($input); $i++) {
    $c = mb_substr($input, $i, 1);
    $array[] = $remap[$c];
}
$star = "(" . implode(',', $array) . ")";
echo $star;
```